# Errors with Javascript preloader and load() command

Tags: javascript

I am scripting some buttons whose `onclick` command loads an external html file and changes the src of an image. However, upon opening the .html file in a browser I'm met with all of my JavaScript code showing in plain-jane ASCII, clearly unexecuted! :(

*EDIT* Fixed the problem with the "script type" command. Now, It seems as though the script itself is not executing at all. Any suggestions about what may be going wrong?

Here's the code:

```
<script='javascript'>

/*image preloader*/

incompanyImage = new Image(); 
incompanyImage.src = " http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/dotshock/dotshock1211/dotshock121100869/16581370-group-of-happy-young-business-people-in-a-meeting-at-office.jpg"; 
/*alt image 1: http://www.123rf.com/photo_16522931_group-of-happy-young-business-people-in-a-meeting-at-office.html */
/*img source: http://www.123rf.com/photo_16581370_group-of-happy-young-business-people-in-a-meeting-at-office.html */

grupoImage = new Image(); 
grupoImage.src = " http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/dotshock/dotshock1209/dotshock120901786/15403105-business-people-team-group-on-a-meeting-have-success-and-make-deal.jpg";
/*img source: http://www.123rf.com/photo_15403105_business-people-team-group-on-a-meeting-have-success-and-make-deal.html */
/*alt images */

particularImage = new Image(); 
particularImage.src = "http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/auremar/auremar1210/auremar121001327/15672624-concerned-business-associates.jpg";
/*img source: http://www.123rf.com/photo_15672624_concerned-business-associates.html */
/*alt images  */

intensivoImage = new Image();
intensivoImage.src = "http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/dotshock/dotshock1211/dotshock121100861/16581384-group-of-happy-young-business-people-in-a-meeting-at-office.jpg";
/*img source male:  http://www.123rf.com/photo_16580996_portrait-of-a-handsome-young-business-man-on-a-meeting-in-offce-with-colleagues-in-background.html */
/*img source female:  http://www.123rf.com/photo_16581362_business-woman-with-her-staff--people-group-in-background-at-modern-bright-office-indoors.html */

tecnicoImage = new Image();
tecnicoImage.src = "http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/dotshock/dotshock1211/dotshock121100861/16581384-group-of-happy-young-business-people-in-a-meeting-at-office.jpg";
/*img source : http://www.123rf.com/photo_16581384_group-of-happy-young-business-people-in-a-meeting-at-office.html */
/*alt image: */


entrevistaImage = new Image();
entrevistaImage.src = "http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/dotshock/dotshock1211/dotshock121100912/16581362-business-woman-with-her-staff--people-group-in-background-at-modern-bright-office-indoors.jpg";
/* img source: http://www.123rf.com/photo_16581362_business-woman-with-her-staff--people-group-in-background-at-modern-bright-office-indoors.html */
/* alt image (better): http://www.123rf.com/photo_16523034_group-of-happy-young-business-people-in-a-meeting-at-office.html */
/*http://www.123rf.com/photo_16523034_group-of-happy-young-business-people-in-a-meeting-at-office.html */
 
palestraImage = new Image();
palestraImage.src = "http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/dotshock/dotshock1204/dotshock120400224/13112547-young-male-business-man-giving-a-presentation-at-a-meeting-seminar-at-modern-conference-room-on-a-ta.jpg";  
/*img source: http://www.123rf.com/photo_13112547_young-male-business-man-giving-a-presentation-at-a-meeting-seminar-at-modern-conference-room-on-a-ta.html */

 
/*these are the buttons for types of english classes offered*/
functon buttonInCompany()
{
$('#desc').load('incompany.html');
document.images["midimg"].src = incompanyImage.src;
}

functon buttonGrupo()
{
$('#desc').load('grupo.html');
document.images["midimg"].src = grupoImage.src;
}

functon buttonParticular()
{
$('#desc').load('particular.html');
document.images["midimg"].src = particularImage.src;
}

functon buttonIntensivo()
{
$('#desc').load('intensivo.html');
document.images["midimg"].src = intensivoImage.src;
}

function buttonEntrevista()
{
$('desc').load('entrevista.html');
document.images["midimg"].src = entrevista.html;    
}    

functon buttonTecnico()
{
$('#desc').load('tecnico.html');
document.images["midimg"].src = tecnicoImage.src;
}

function buttonPalestra()
{
$('#desc').load('palestra.html');
document.images["midimg"].src = palestraImage.src;
}

</script>
```

Now comes the HTML.

```
<div>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><img name="midimg" width="233" height="350"  class="art-lightbox" src="images/Fotolia_5170186_X-01.jpg"><br></p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="desc" name="desc">hasdf</p>
</div>
  <div class="art-button" onClick:"buttonParticular()">Aulas Particulares</div>
  <div class="art-button" onClick:"buttonGrupo()">Aulas em Grupo</div>
  <div class="art-button" onClick:"buttonInCompany()">Aulas in-Company</div>
  <div class="art-button" onClick:"buttonIntensivo()">Aulas Intensivos</div>
  <div class="art-button" onClick:"buttonEntrevista()">Aulas para Entrevista</div>
  <div class="art-button" onClick:"buttonTecnico()"> Aulas sobre sua Area</div>
  <div class="art-button" onClick:"buttonPalestra()">Palestras</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<script='javascript'>` - either clean this tag completely (`<script>` should suffice on any worthy browser) or replace it with `<script type="javascript">`.

Comment: First, place javascript code inside _<script type='javascript'>_ instead of _<script='javascript'>_.

Comment: great, wow, that was an easy solution! :) 

Although now I can see that my buttons aren't working properly, either. Dunno why. Is there anything wrong with the commands inside the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (as others have commented, but not posted as answers) is your opening `<script='javascript'>`. You're looking for:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

also: some of your `function` declarations are misspelled 'functon'

and you should follow the `onclick` with an `=` instead of a `:`

```
<div onclick="...">
```

Comment: thanks andre. also, do you notice any problems with the commands within the functions? they don't seem to be executing.

Comment: yes, two things: 1) some `function`s are misspelled 'functon' 2) it should be `onclick="...."`

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `<script='javascript'>` to `<script type='javascript'>`. Because of no space after `script` browse get a tag called `script='javascript'` (which is not familiar to it) instead of `script`

Also:

```
<div class="art-button" onClick:"buttonParticular()">Aulas Particulares</div>
```

should be

```
<div class="art-button" onClick="buttonParticular()">Aulas Particulares</div>
```

In html, you should place `=` between attribute name (`onclick` in your case) and value (`"buttonParticular()"`)

Comment: thanks FAngel. also, do you notice any problems with the commands within the functions? they don't seem to be executing.